# Microsoft OLEDB Provider for ODBC Driver error '80004005'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, oledb

I was trying to setup a classical asp project but i am getting this error:

> [image: This]

And my connection was this:

```
MM_Client_STRING = "dsn=Sql_ecomply;uid=sa;pwd=Calv;"
```

After googling i found to change the connection to this:

```
MM_client_STRING = "Provider=R2014;Data Source=NAUMAN;Initial Catalog=ecomply_V4;User ID=sa;Password=Calv;"
```

Then error changes to this:

> [image: This]

Can you guys help me, where I am missing something or I might add or subtract anything.

After Alex K. Suggested me to do it with 32-bit admin it works. But stuck on new thing i.e. this:

[image: This]

Comment: What database platform are you attempting to connect to?  Sounds like you created a 64bit DSN try creating via the 32bit admin @ C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it works, i edited the question i am stuck it now. Can you help? @AlexK.

Comment: @NaumanMoazzam That's it, move on to the next thing. This isn't a forum please don't treat it like one. That error message is very clear, "Parent Paths" are disallowed so make sure you aren't using `../` as a way to navigate to any `<!-- #include ... -->` statements in the ASP page or enable "Parent Paths" in ASP settings in IIS.

Comment: I've never heard of a provider called 'R2014', but your no dsn connection string looks like it might work if you use `"Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=NAUMAN;Initial Catalog=ecomply_V4;User ID=sa;Password=Calv;"`.  And if you're using Sql Server Express then you may need to use 'NAUMANN\SQLEXPRESS' as your data source.  More info here - https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using 64Bit DSN for the 1st solution as Alex suggested, go try with 32 Bit DSN.
And for the second question you edited.
This is the problem occurred when you use IIS 6.0, Microsoft disabled Parent-Path default in IIS 6.0 for security reasons & it is discouraged to enable it.
Instead use **virtual** keyword with the exact path i.e.

```
<!--- include virtual = "/File Name" -->
```

instead of using this:

```
<!--- include name ="../file name" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second error, it sounds as though you're trying to run Classic ASP on a 64 bit application pool.  From within IIS, click on 'Application Pools', right click on the App Pool used by your site, then choose 'Advanced Settings'.  Change 'Managed Pipeline Mode' to 'Classic' and 'Enable 32-Bit Applications' to 'True' and it should then work.

Comment: Tried that, and it works as AlexK. suggested. Now stuck on another problem. Which is edited in question

Comment: @NaumanMoazzam seems like you need a IIS Administrator, the problems you are encountering are Classic ASP 101. It even tells you the problem in the error message, did you even look up what a "Parent Path" is?